# Interacting with Eclipse plugin from external application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm wondering if there is any way to interact with a plugin from an external application ?

Say I have  an eclipse plugin running. I want to write another standalone application which calls this plugin and gets some result from it . Is this possible ?

Comment: It is possible, and the techniques to achieve it have nothing to do with the fact that it is an Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: Can you give me some details of the techniques you are talking about ?

Comment: On my project I used Netty. The code is online and you can [check it out](https://github.com/mtopolnik/request-age/blob/master/src/com/ingemark/requestage/StressTestServer.java) if you want. In that project, my plug-in starts another JVM process and communicates using TCP and basic Java serialization.